# As issuer of a token how do I know the owners of a token bought on an exchange

Tags: transactions, dapp-development

If I create a membership token = own the token to get rewards - how as the issuer of the token do I know the new owners of the token [so they are registered for rewards as owners] if the token is bought on an listed exchange after the ICO

Answer (score 0):

An ERC20 token on Ethereum is just a contract that implements the [ERC20 interface](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md), which includes a public mapping called `balanceOf`. You can use it to check the balance of any account. If an account has tokens, then you'll be able to see how many they have.

Perhaps you need to be able to do more than that (e.g. enumerate all the token holders)? If so, please elaborate on your requirements and where you're stuck in your implementation.

Comment: I am writing up the smart contract specification for the developer - the ICO is covered off as each token sold creates access to a platform as in the rules of the smart contract - the issue I had to work through was for anyone buying the token on an OTC exchange [POLINIEX] - how will the smart contract know that the buyer of this token has a token so as to gain  access to the platform - apologies not the coder but am learning to code smart contracts so this is a user test       Hope this helps

Comment: When someone buys through an exchange, the exchange will call "transfer" or "transferFrom" on your token's contract. That's how the sale happens.